# Different cookie values returned from different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, redux

I am trying to retrieve values stored in the cookie from a child component in a React application and also retrieving the same value in my Redux `store.js` file and my root component.

The value in the `store.js` corresponds perfectly with what is stored in the Cookies storage and for some reason the value returned in the `store.js` is different from that returned in the root component which is different from the one returned in the child component.

Is there a reason of why this could be happening?

I don't have a really good code sample to demo this but I created this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ox72406m9y) to try and explain my point.

Thanks.

Comment: You use wrong approach. With Redux all of your state data should be stored in a single place - Redux's store. And all components should only access that store, they shouldn't read Cookies directly. If you want to persist state in Cookies, you have to use middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a path / for the cookie, otherwise it might be created with another one

`Cookies.set("foo", "value", { expires: 7, path: "/" });`

Comment: I just added that and still nothing. I'm still getting different values in the different files.

Comment: did you try maybe to have the cookie service separated from components ? If only one service takes care of the whole cookie logic, you won't have that issue anymore

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing but I need to check for a condition in the Cookie within the child component.

At the moment though, all the Cookie logic is being done in Redux `store.js`, only if there was a way to tell the components the Cookie value from the `store.js`. I've tried dispatching actions but the problem still persists. The value in `store.js` gets the original value ahead of the other files.